# Is there a way to grab the names of the files that glob parses through?

Tags: python-2.7, glob

I am using the glob module to parse through a bunch of text files. Here is the line of that code:

```
for file in g.glob('*.TXT'):
    for col in csv.DictReader(open(file,'rU')):
```

It works fine but is there a way to grab the names of the files that it iterates through? Im thinking this is not possible since it just looks for any files with the suffix '.TXT'. But I just thought I would ask.

Comment: Do you mean all files that are checked whether or not they match the glob, or all matched file names?

Comment: Well in this case the ones that would be brought into the program. These files go into a particular folder so it would be the files that match the glob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [`glob.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.glob) returns only a list of matching file names, it's not possible to fetch all the file names considered using just this function. That would be a job for [`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir).

If you only want to keep track of the matched files, you can store the return value of `glob()` before iterating over it:

```
filenames = g.glob('*.TXT')

for filename in filenames:
    for col in csv.DictReader(open(filename,'rU')):
        ...
```

Also note that I changed the name `file` to `filename`, because that's more precise.